# Differentiation equations and Series Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

When progressing through a worksheet for series I've stumbled across these form of problems which seem to boggle my mind. It does seem like it requires *Maclaurins* series however the approach seems to be somewhat different *(possibly by parial? Doesn't seem so though)*. The bigger issue is the fact that there's no question, there's simply the exercise with the following problem:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(2x-1)e^x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

---

After re-arranging it simplified it down to $$-e^x(1+2x)^{-1}$$

However not sure how to go from here. Am I expected to work out the expansion regularly, multiple it by $-e^x$ then differentiate it?

---

I kindly ask to provides me with ways to go around this problem, even if it completely differs from my approach.

EDIT - I'd also like to add that the issue why this somehow boggles me if the fact that I'm not asked to do anything particular, therefore even if I were to work the expansion as I've mentioned, till what degree of $x$ would I normally do it to?

Comment: I think that $y=\frac{e^x}{1+2 x}$; sign error somewhere ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There doesn't seem to be any errors anywhere.

Comment: The  minus sign in front of your last expression, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is $$y(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+2x}+C$$ rewrite the integrand in the form
$$\frac{e^x(1+2x)-2e^x}{(1+2x)^2}$$

Comment: Could I kindly ask vaguely how you got to that conclusion? Did you integrate?

Comment: @Juxhin Your equation was $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$.  Integration gives the answer.

Comment: @Mike - Thank you very much, wasn't aware it was that simple.